# Can a discontinuous function be increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

How would we decide increasing or decreasing function if the function is not differentiable? Can a discontinuous function be increasing or decreasing?
And can it be monotonic?

Comment: Let $~\lfloor x\rfloor~$ refer to the *floor* of $~x,~$ (i.e. the largest integer $~\leq x~$) for $~x \in \Bbb{R}.~$ Let $~f(x) = x + \lfloor x\rfloor.~$  Then, $~x < y \implies f(x) < f(y),~$ so $~f(x)~$ is a strictly increasing function that is discontinuous at each $~x \in \Bbb{Z}.$

Comment: To answer your questions:

(1) A function $f$ is increasing if $f(x) \leq f(y)$ whenever $x \leq y$ and strictly increasing if these inequalities are both strict.  It does not depend on the function having a derivative.

(2) An increasing function need not be differentiable or even continuous at every point.  

(3) However, an increasing function of a real variable $x$ on an open interval $a < x < b$ is differentiable at all but a null set of points - see Lebesgue's theorem.

Comment: The ideas of "increasing" and "decreasing" do not rely on the notions of differentiability.

Comment: To expand on what WA Don said, it can be mentioned that the set of points of discontinuity of a monotonic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is countable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a function $f$ which is discontinuous in every neighbourhood and strictly increasing everywhere. Let $r_0,r_1,r_2,...$ be an enumeration of the set $D$ of finite decimals between $r_0=0$ and $1$ such that the $0$-place decimals are counted first, the $1$-place decimals next, and so on.* Let $f(r_0)=0$ and, for each $k\in\Bbb N$, define $f(r_{k+1})=f(r_k)+2^{-k}$. For $x\in[0\,\pmb,\,1)\setminus D$, define $$f(x):=\sup\{f(r):r\in D\,;\,r<x\}.$$ All other values of $f$ are determined by the identity $f(x+1)=f(x)+2\,$ ($x\in\Bbb R$).

* For example, $(r_0,r_1,...)=(0; 0.1, ...,0.9;0.01,...,0.99;\,...)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, x \in \mathbb Q \implies f(x)=\tan x. x\in \mathbb Q^c \implies f(x)=0.$

It's only continuous at $x=0$. Not differentiable anywhere. If $x,y \in \mathbb Q \cap(-\pi/2,\pi/2), x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$. Since $\tan$ is periodic, the function is understood by analyzing only this interval.

Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$ ,$\forall p \in \mathbb Q, \delta \in \mathbb R, \delta>0, \exists q\in \mathbb Q, |p-q|<\delta$. Something similar can be said about two elements from $\mathbb Q^c$.

So the limit of $\frac{\tan p-\tan q}{p-q}, q\to p$ exists and is equal to $\sec^2 p$ if $p$ and $q$ are both rational. If they are both irrational, that limit is 0. Since the limits aren't equal, the function isn't differentiable.

So there's a clear sense in which a non-trivial part of the function is increasing, yet it isn't differentiable.

Comment: I thought the point of examples like this is that the function is neither differentiable **nor** increasing. Who talks about this "non-trivial part of the function" that is increasing, and isn't that "non-trivial part" also differentiable by the same reasoning? I guess you're trying to make some kind of answer to the original question, but I can't see what it is.